# RewriteEngine adding .php to query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm rewriting a query to a SEO friendly URL..
Basically, I'm rewriting
`http://example.com/forums/category?v=Name`
to
`http://example.com/forums/category/Name`

My problem is that the $_GET['v'] is returning `Name.php` instead of `Name`.. Here is my .htaccess:

```
<Files .htaccess> 
order allow,deny 
deny from all 
</Files> 

ErrorDocument 400 /404.htm
ErrorDocument 401 /404.htm
ErrorDocument 403 /404.htm
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
ErrorDocument 500 /404.htm

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /forums/view\.php\?v=([^&]+)&a=(.+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /forums/view/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/view.php?v=$1&a=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /forums/category\.php\?v=([^&]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /forums/category/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/category/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/category.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `$_GET['v']` in which file?

Comment: `http://example.com/forums/category/Computing` returns `Computing.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

these 2 strings mean that if your file is absent (and `http://example.com/forums/category/Name` is obviously absent) you transform it to `http://example.com/forums/category/Name.php` and the rules proceed further - so you have `Name.php` as a parameter in your category.php instead of `Name`

To solve your problem just move these 2 strings below other rules.

Answer (score 0):

The following rule matches before the rule that writes that part to the query string.

```
#First matched rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

#Before this rule
RewriteRule ^forums/category/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/category.php?v=$1 [L]
```

It seems that the rule that is matched first is meant to be 'if-all-other-cases-fail-do-this', so you should move that rule to the bottom.